# Having a plural and singlar name when using DisplayName in Dynamic Data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have an ASP.Net Dynamic Data linq-to-SQL website with two tables I'm generating a gridview for. `System_States` and `System_Counties`. In `System_Counties` there's a foreign key that points to the state it's in, in the `System_States` table. In order to have a user friendly table and column name, I have

```
[MetadataType(typeof(StateMetadata))]
public partial class System_State
{
}

[DisplayName("States")]
public class StateMetadata
{
    ....
```

Which works nicely, but now I've lost the auto-pluralization used by Linq-to-SQL. Before I used `DisplayName`, The States table had System_States over it, but the column in the Counties grid showing which state it was in said System_State. But now with `[DisplayName("States")]` both the States table header and the County column name are "States." Is there a built in way for me to still have a plural and singular name when using `DisplayName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom meta attribute to handle single and plural usage :

[SingularTableName("Budget")]

[DisplayName("Budgets")]

public partial class Budget { }